# Fuerte: Install bullet from source

Tags: ros, bullet, source, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently setting up with Fuerte and need to install bullet so I can use the geometry package. However, I need to install from source and the repository given on the ROS.org bullet page seems to have been removed. Is there somewhere I can get the fuerte version of bullet still?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107856/fuerte:-install-bullet-from-source/) by [DoubtedGoat](https://answers.ros.org/users/9616/doubtedgoat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
i found it through gen_rosinstall.py, you can find it here: ros-dry-releases.googlecode.com/svn/download/stacks/bullet/bullet-2.79/bullet-2.79.tar.bz2

---

Originally posted by [hjeldin](https://answers.ros.org/users/9596/hjeldin/) with karma: 26 on 2013-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1